# Purpose of HLFS

Tags: lfs

I recently found out about the [LFS project](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) and their sub-projects. Is the HLFS Project only for

> production-quality servers, routers, and firewalls

or is it also recommended for securing your desktop PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HLFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hlfs/) page:

```
Hardened Linux From Scratch (HLFS) is a project that provides you 
with step-by-step instructions for building your own customized and 
hardened Linux system entirely from source
```

The project will only be "initially geared towards building production-quality servers, routers, and firewalls" the list you quote from that page. You can extend it with BLFS packages. The [BLFS book](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/) was updated last September, after 5 years, so is fairly up-to-date.